# Hide the tab arrow in BBEdit

Tags: bbedit

So I'm trying to make the switch from Textmate to BBEdit and I've gotten past most differences except for one...the little arrows BBEdit puts in to show tab.

For each time I hit tab a little arrow is displayed on the screen.

Is it possible to turn this off?  I found detab but that just removes the tabs in favor of spaces.
I just don't want to see that little arrow.  I've looked through preferences and search a little for an obvious answer but I can't seem to find anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out is was not a BBEdit issue as much as the font I was using.  I switched to a more standard font and the tab arrows went away.